# Is there a way to randomize each cell in a grid?

Tags: python

I've been trying the Conways Game of Life problem, as it was extension for school, but i cant figure out how to randomize each cell in the grid(either alive, dead, with L and D representing them).
Some variables are just there for later(the ones at the start)
Heres my code so far:

```
import random
import math

generations = 0
liveCellCount = 0
deadCellCount = 0
cellState = "LD"

width = 20
height = 20
grid = []
row = []
state = random.choice(cellState)
p = 1

for i in range(width):
    row.append(state)
for i in range(height):
    grid.append(row)


while p < 2:
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[i])
    p = p + 1
```

also ignore my p = 1 stuff, i couldnt be bothered to change it

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to randomise the states for every cell in the grid. I've identified the following problems with your code.

```
state = random.choice(cellState)

for i in range(width):
    row.append(state)
```

You've chosen a random state once and you're reusing that for every cell in the grid. Consider putting the random choice function into a for loop so it chooses a new one for every cell.

```
for i in range(height):
    grid.append(row)
```

You're also using the same list for every row in the grid.

Here's my suggested solution:

```
import random

width = 20
height = 20
grid = []

for i in range(height):
    row = []
    for j in range(width):
        state = random.choice("LD")
        row.append(state)
    grid.append(row)

# Print the grid below
```

Notice that a new list is created for every row in the grid. This is to make sure that every row can be different, unlike your example where you've reused the same row object for the whole grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import random 
import math 
generations = 0
liveCellCount = 0 
deadCellCount = 0 
cellState = "LD" 
width = 20 
height = 20 
grid = [] 
row = [] 
state = random.choice

for i in range(width): 
    row.append(state(cellState))
    for i in range(height): 
        grid.append(row) 
print(grid)
```